# cannot push to github repository

Tags: git, javascript, visual-studio-code, github

i have removed PROJECTJS repo and want to use task-manager-js repo,when i type:

```
git remote -v
```

it gives me :

```
ProjectJS       Task-Manager-JS (fetch)
ProjectJS       Task-Manager-JS (push)
origin  https://github.com/user/ProjectJS.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/ProjectJS.git (push)
task-manager-js https://github.com/user/Task-Manager-JS..git (fetch)
task-manager-js https://github.com/user/Task-Manager-JS..git (push)
```

and it won't let me upload to  task-manager-js. it gives :

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user/ProjectJS.git/' not found
```

can someone help? i am using manjaro

Comment: It's difficult to tell the problem with the modified URLs. Is the extra trailing backslash in the error message accurate? Is the double period in the `git remote -v` output accurate?

Comment: user is used instead of my username on github but that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't removed the reference to the `ProjectJS` repo. In fact, the default push target for `git` is `origin`, which is what it's trying to do.

- Remove all the remotes with:

```
git remote remove ProjectJS
git remote remove origin
git remote remove task-manager-js
```

- Add the proper `origin`:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/charbeleidd/Task-Manager-JS..git
```

- Push

A few tips:

- Review [GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), it'll make your life *much* easier.
- I would also advise you to remove the trailing `.` from the repo name. While it is technically ok, it's likely going to confuse others when trying to work with your repo.
- Don't make our lives harder by changing the output of your commands to hide something which can be found with a 3 second GitHub search. If it's public, someone will find it. If you don't want it public, set the repository type to private.

Comment: thank you very much !